# Symfony2 hierarchical security checks

Tags: symfony, architecture, permissions, acl

I have a big problem with my architecture of my application. I have different services for example:

**PlayerService:**
- createPlayer (Method will create a player in database, do some api calls and call ScoreService->createScore)

**ScoreService:**
- createScore (Method will create an score entry in database and also do some api calls.

There are two different acl permissions for both service methods for example.

- Player -> write
- Score -> write

The problem is if a user has the permission to write a player but don´t have the permission to write a score the creation of a player will fails and i have a inconsistent state of data because some of api calls are done in the createPlayer method.

What is the best approach to handle this situation? Probably, i have to pre check all necessary permissions at the beginnig of any method call.

The second question is, what is about events? If a event is fired and the listener do some actions that requires a permission, the request will also fail.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you have to do all the required checks before making any change.

But there's something else.

You say that a user may have the permission to create a player, but not the permission to create a score. If this is a valid situation, "createPlayer" and "createScore" should be called in two different steps. I.e. in your controller (pseudo code):

```
if ($this->userHasCreatePlayerRights($user)) {
    $player = $this->container->get('app.player')->createPlayer($user);
}
if ($this->userHasCreateScoreRights($user)) {
    $score = $this->container->get('app.score')->createScore($player);
}
```